# Serialize With Options Configuration Blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm using serialize_with_options ( http://www.viget.com/extend/simple-apis-using-serializewithoptions/ ) in a rails project and have been using named blocks for rendering as per the example on the linked page:

```
class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  serialize_with_options do
    methods   :average_rating, :avatar_url
    except    :email, :claim_code
    includes  :talks
  end

  serialize_with_options :with_email do
    methods   :average_rating, :avatar_url
    except    :claim_code
    includes  :talks
  end

end
```

Then I can call the second block configuration with @speaker.to_xml(:with_email).  This works well, however, I'd like to figure out how to call this block when I have an array of objects.  For example, the following does not work:

```
@speakers = Speaker.all
@speakers.to_xml(:with_email)
```

Which returns a "TypeError: can't dup Symbol" error.  This makes sense to me since Array hasn't been configured to use serialize_with_options.  How can I get this tag to be passed on to the individual speaker objects when running .to_xml and render all speakers :with_email?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem. 

I also attempted doing @speakers.as_json(:only => :email), but the problem now is that it is trying to use the defined serialize_with_options so it is including :talks and :methods.

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't.  I worked around it in some way (can't remember how at the moment). I think the gist was to avoid the named block altogether.  Sorry that's not too helpful...

Answer (score 1):

In your above example, @speakers is a Array object. You need to implement / override the to_xml there . Then i should work:

```
class Array
    def to_xml (with_email)
        self.each do |element|
            element.to_xml(with_email)
        end
    end
end
```